# How to do a linear regression into a BIRT report?

Tags: statistics, report, birt, regression, linear-regression

How to make a linear regression on the chart displayed into your BIRT report.
I have x and y data... but I don't see any function on eclipse BIRT to generate the linear regression...

Any idea ?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a linear regression in BIRT. That said it should be trivial to create a BIRT extension that would do this for you.  For an example of BIRT extension points have a look at the [birt-functions-lib project](http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/birt-functions-lib/) on Eclipse Labs

Answer (score 0):

Birt report in SpagoBI:
Firstly we have to create new SpagoBI project in SpagoBI  studio and we have to go business analysis and have to right click on that Business Analysis and goto reports and create Birt report  and in Report design we have to  drag and drop the table or charts what ever we required. then connectivity to the database and have to create the data base and data set for that connection.

flow of creation of Birt Report or Jasper :
open studio---> open new SpagoBI project--> goto Business Analysis right click R/C---> select reports-->  select the Birt or jasper report--->open Report design-->and Drag and drop the table or charts etc.., and connectivity  to database as per the Excell sheet or DataBase conectivities.